# how to write this question in java or how i could connect one client and 4 server with each other

Tags: java, netbeans

You are to build a system with one client and 4 servers.

The client attempts to connect to server 1; it fails

```
 The failure is due to the fact that the server starts after the client
```

Then attempts to connect to server 2; it fails

```
The failure is due to the fact that server 2 is busy, and responds to the client request late.
```

Then attempts to connect to server 3; it fails

```
The failure is due to incorrect port number used by the client
```

Then the client succeeds to connect to the client.

The client prints the results of its 4 attempts:

Fail to connect to server 1

Fails to connect to server 2

Fails to connect to server 3

Succeeds to connect to server 4

Comment: We can't write your homework for you. If you have no idea how to start, ask your teacher or someone else. If you have a **specific** problem, edit your question to be about that.

Answer (score 0):

This kind of logic is normally better to be handled outside your application but if you want to implement it on the application, you should consider using libraries such as:

1. [Failsafe](https://jodah.net/failsafe/)
2. [Resilience4j](https://github.com/resilience4j/resilience4j)

With resilience4j you have the Retry where you can define the number of attempts and then on each attempt you change the url.

```
    val retry = Retry.of("retrying", RetryConfig.custom<RetryConfig>()
        .maxAttempts(3)
        .intervalFunction { attempt: Int -> (attempt * 2).toLong() }
        .build())

    val responses = ArrayDeque<Response>()
    responses.add(Response(Status.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR))
    responses.add(Response(Status.OK))

    val retrying = ResilienceFilters.RetryFailures(retry,
        isError = { r: Response -> !r.status.successful }
    ).then {
        val response = responses.removeFirst()
        println("trying request, will return " + response.status)
        response
    }
```